# How to obtain real time updated DB cloned

Tags: sql, ssms, clone, replication

I have a local server on which there are some DB,I don't want my co-workers to operate directly on the table and potentially cause some damage on the data.
But, at the same time, I need that they work with the real time updated DB.
Is there any way possible to do this?

Comment: You mean  you want the to have read only access? Yes, this is possible. Where are you having difficultly? Have you looked at the [fixed database roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles)?

Comment: Not exactly, my co-workers need to have all permission but they need to work on a DB copy

Comment: Seems like you should make a backup of the database, restore in on their local development environments, and then use good source control solutions.

Comment: I need to some automation in order to have an update each day. I don't need that date will be saved